# Extracting Backtrace from Binary Dump file and ELF- Linux

Tags: linux, crash, gdb, crash-dumps

I have a dump file of type Binary say **mydump.bin** and an ELF file say **myelf.elf**.
I need to extract the BackTrace , PC , LR symbols from them.
I used crash Tool command as below.

```
crash -s -i bt.txt mydump.bin myelf.elf
```

bt.txt has the follwing content

```
bt > myBT.txt
exit
```

but when I run the above command I get that mydump.Bin is not a supported format.
How to modify this command or is there any other way to do it either as a Linux command or via Perl script?

Edit:
What I exactly want is in place of vmcore in

```
crash -s vmcore vmlinux
```

how can I replace vmcore with mydunmp.Bin

Comment: What does `file mydump.bin` say? Is it an ELF coredump?

Comment: yeah it is the binary file collected after crash

Comment: Please add the `file` output to the question.